# DbSet Find method returns null

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

In the following code the value of user1 is null, while user2 is not null. I was debugging the first line and I saw that it get the values from user db and start setting them but for some reason I get null.

```
using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
    var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DBContext>();
    User user1 = dbContext.Users.Find(id);
    User user2 = dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id.Value == id.Value);
}
```

but if I reverse the lines putting user2 first, I will get a value in user1

```
using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
    var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ELearningContext>();
    User user2 = dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id.Value == id.Value);
    User user1 = dbContext.Users.Find(id);
}
```

Any ideas?

I have id as a key:

```
builder.HasKey(c => c.Id);
```

**UPDATED**

I'm using EF core and my config is:

UserMap

```
public class UserMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(c => c.Id);

        builder
            .Property(c => c.Id)
            .HasColumnType("nvarchar(40)")
            .HasConversion(
                v => v.Value,
                v => new UserId(v)
            )
            .IsRequired();

        builder
            .Property(c => c.Email)
            .HasColumnType("nvarchar(60)")
            .HasConversion(
                v => v.Value,
                v => new UserEmail(v)
            )
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

Context:

```
public class DBContext : DbContext
{
    public DBContext(DbContextOptions opt) : base(opt) { }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new UserMap());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the *type* of `Id` property and `id` variable?

Comment: @IvanStoev Id and id are a ValueObject

Comment: Most probably that's the problem. EF might not generate correct SQL in the first case (when the entity isn't in the cache and has to be retrieved from database). In the second case the object is already in memory and the key is found. How is value object mapped - with value converter? Please include small but full repro. And specify the type and version of the EF used (EF6 or EF Core) .

Comment: @IvanStoev I've just updated the description. I think the SQL is correct because debugging I can see how it retrieve the data from database and setting them for the user but for some reason I get null object.

Comment: I see. Tried something like that with EF Core 3.1.10 and can't reproduce. `Find` works as expected, and `FirstOrDefault` produces exception saying that expression `.Where(c => c.Id.Value == __id_Value_0)` could not be translated.

Comment: My recommendation would be to use simple types for your keys. String PKs are bad enough, but then wrapping them with a ValueObject? (Not something I like to look at first thing on a Monday morning! :)